# Why does the CPython interpreter ignore TERM when run in container?

Tags: python, signal, container

If I start a Python process in a container with

```
docker run --name python python python3 -c "import time; time.sleep(3600)"
```

And try to terminate this on another console with

```
docker stop python
```

the interpreter is not stopped.  Instead, docker has got to kill the process after a grace period (10s by default).

However, a simple

```
python3 -c "import time; time.sleep(3600)"
```

on the command line can be aborted immediately by sending a TERM to it.

What is the reason for this asymmetry?

Comment: I don't know docker, but I suspect its `stop` command does send a different signal than `TERM` to the container. Edit: Have you tried `docker kill python`? (Alternatively to send SIGTERM: `docker kill --signal=SIGTERM python`)

Comment: See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/: “The main process inside the container will receive SIGTERM, and after a grace period, SIGKILL.“

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asymmetry stems from UNIX itself.  Linux' `man 2 kill` manpage says:

> The only signals that can be sent to process ID 1, the init process, are those for which init has explicitly installed signal handlers. This is done to assure the system is not brought down accidentally.

Python by default installs no handlers.  If the Python interpreter runs not as PID 1, this means that the default action is taken, which for SIGTERM means to abort the process.  If it runs as PID 1, there is no default action.  Thus, nothing happens.